# Cyclist script bug?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I have previously asked about this question, and whilst doing some debugging, I have finally found the issue with my code, however I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

I have created a spawn system that spawns cyclists and instantly begin to cycle them forwards, I have 1 script that makes each cyclist move forwards, and another that makes them stop and continue off when another player or cyclist is in front of it, **THIS** is the script that has the issue.

To quickly summarise, whenever a *cyclist(a)* is stopped by a player, and another *cyclist(b)* get stopped by the cyclist in front, a boolean triggers which turns `playerInside` and `cyclistInside` to `true`. This is fine. However once the player moves out the way, the first *cyclist(a)* has `playerInside` set to `false`, which is correct, but `cyclistInside` is still set to `true`. This is because the cyclist behind him is still detecting the one in front. So it doesn't seem like the scripts are working independently for each cyclist.

I've spent some time debugging to really find the issue here, and this is what I've found.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cyclistStoping : MonoBehaviour
{

public VehicleMove cyclistMovement;

public Animator CycleAnims;

// bools

public bool playerInside;
public bool cyclistInside;

private void Start()
{
    playerInside = false;
    cyclistInside = false;
}

// implement delay

private void Update()
{
    if (playerInside == false && cyclistInside == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine(timeDelay());
    }
}

// player or cyclist (INSIDE)
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" ) {
        playerInside = true;
        cyclistMovement.vehicleMovement = 0.0f;
    }

    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Cyclist")
    {
        cyclistInside = true;
        cyclistMovement.vehicleMovement = 0.0f;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        playerInside = false;
    }

    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Cyclist")
    {
        cyclistInside = false;
    }

}

IEnumerator timeDelay()
{
    // wait before moving off
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    if (playerInside == false && cyclistInside == false)
    {
        cyclistMovement.vehicleMovement = 0.1f;
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }
}

}
```

At this point, once the player moves away from the cyclist, the first cyclist (and the ones waiting behind) won't move off, because they are waiting for the first cyclist to move, which won't move due to the `cyclistInside` being set to `true` even though there's no cyclist infront.

I expect the cyclist to move off once the player is no longer in front of it, and so fourth with the rest of them.

Comment: I would suggest creating a LayerMask, using a raycast with that layer mask in an update in order to determine if the cyclist can move.  The LayerMask should only have the objects that cane make the cyclist stop in it.  this way you dont have to rely on triggerEnter and exit.

Comment: You can find an example of how to cast here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html

Comment: You can also try to make it so the collider, that detects other bikes, is just in front of the bikes and doesn't collide with bikes at the back

Comment: @AliBaba The box collider is infront of each bike, and is the same collider that detects both cyclists and the player, is this bad? Should I have 2 separate colliders to detect the player and cyclist?

Comment: @OpenSource Having the same collider for bikes and the player is fine. I'm just suspecting, that the collider of the bike in the front is so big, that it collides with the bike in the back. You could try making the colliders smaller. The code should be fine as is

Comment: @AliBaba I've updated the question so you can see how the collider is set up

Comment: @AliBaba I wouldnt say the code is good, in the circumstance a cyclist collides with either a player or cyclist they will stop now imagine the case, where a cyclist collides with the player, he gets set false to move, player moves, no longer colliding, but the cyclist is still delayed due to the IEnumerator, a second cyclist collides with the cyclist in front of him both wiill be set to stop move, and never move again, for this reason you should do a cast, or do a check to see what direction the collider you are colliding with is, and ignore cyclist behind you.

Comment: @OpenSource Is the collider of the collision detector on a different gameobject than the collider of the bike? It should be, else the bike in the front WILL detect the bike in the back

Comment: @OpenSource to make your code work the way it's written, and without changing your hierchy tooo much, just add a direction check, (Vector3.dot with forward vector and collider position) if it is in front set stop to true, if it is behind ignore it.

Comment: @AliBaba last time I check OnTriggerEnter gets called on every script that is associated with teh trigger, this would include if the "detection" object was a child of the cyclist. the top cyclist script onTrigger would be called still (Infact I just tested it and its still the case)

Comment: @Eddge Yeah, that's why the Collider and Script for the collision detection should be on the child object. Then it works fine

Comment: @AliBaba it would still stop the cyclist even on the child object, since the trigger on the Cyclist script would still be called.

Comment: @AliBaba I've update the question with another image, I'll also look into adding a direction check if I can't get passed this issue this way

Comment: @ OpenSource Try putting the `CyclistStoping` script and the Collider, that is the trigger on a new child object and it should work :)

Comment: I've been testing this for 5 minutes and I believe it's actually working!! Can you explain why this was an issue before?

Comment: Hi @AliBaba, could I get an update on this? Quite interested to know more about this fix?

Comment: If detection and collision of a bicicle are on the same gameobject and the same layer, then if the collision-detection of the bicicle in the back hits the collider of the bicicle in the front, the collider of the bicicle in the front triggers also. OnTriggerEnter not only gets called, if a trigger-collider hits a non-trigger-collider, but also if a non-trigger-collider gets hit by a trigger-collider.